# How to update a field by itself in linq2db

Tags: sql-update, linq2db

I mean,
how can I translate the query

```sql
update myTable 
    set myField1 = myField1 + 1 
where myField2 = 'xyz'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways:

```cs
db.MyTable
   .Where(x => x.MyField2 == "xyz")
   .Set(x => x.MyField1, prev => prev.MyField1 + 1)
   .Update();
```

```cs
db.MyTable
   .Where(x => x.MyField2 == "xyz")
   .Update(prev => new MyTable { MyField1 = prev.MyField1 + 1 });
```

```cs
db.MyTable
   .Update(x => x.MyField2 == "xyz", 
      new MyTable { MyField1 = prev.MyField1 + 1 });
```